# What happens when we have many requests (multi-core architecture) to write data to the same RAM address?

Tags: multithreading, memory, parallel-processing, operating-system, synchronization

Suppose, we have Thread1 and Thread2.

They are running on different CPUs cores (simultaneously). And they request to write data (X) to the same address. Where Thread1 X = 8 (0000 1000), and Thread2 X = 6 (0000 0110).

Are these request synchronized by the memory controller or channel architecture, bus or smtng else? If it is possible to run these request simultaneously (two signal at the same time using the same single channel), then it is possible to have problems with consistency, where result will be something like this X = 14 (0000 1110). (because these two signal have impact on each other).

This question is more about how the single RAM module handles simultaneous access requests by different CPUs cores rather than about race condition, cache coherence protocol.

Thanks for helping me!

It seems that only one request to write/read the data from the same address are executed by RAM at the single time. In the other case it is possible to have problems with consistency. (x = 8, and x = 6 expected because of race condition, but x = 14 because of distorted signal is unexpected).

Comment: AFAIK, *cache coherence protocols* prevent two request to be done on the same address simultaneously. Modern hardware are NUMA ones so each CPU has its own (set of) RAM and its own memory controller. When a CPU want to write in a RAM that is not managed by its own controller, then it send a request to other CPUs and the request is then managed by the remote CPU. Request on the same addresses are serialized by a controller. The same thing happens for caches.

Comment: Besides, the RAM bus transfer data in a serialized way. Accesses can be interleaved to different banks but each bank compute incoming requests (somehow) serially. The way RAMs operate is pretty complex so a book is certainly the best way to really understand this.

Comment: Yeah, in practice, one write wins the race but loses the prize when the data is overwritten by the later write.